# How to use generic function to reduce this duplicate code

Tags: rust

I have lots of code similar to below：

```
let metadata = Some(meta::ObjectMeta {
    name: Some(apple.name.clone()),
}),
```

```
let metadata = Some(meta::ObjectMeta {
    name: Some(orange.name.clone()),
}),
```

I hope to write a generic function something like:

```
fn get_meta<T>(args: T) -> Option<meta::ObjectMeta> {
   Some(meta::ObjectMeta {
       name: Some(args.name.clone()),
   })
}
let metadata = get_meta(self);
```

But how could I make sure that the generic type T has the field `name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When introducing a generic type `T` like you do, you cannot do anything with it: you cannot call methods, cannot access fields and so on. You just don't know anything about the type. The only way to add "features" to the type is via trait bounds, e.g. `<T: Foo>` if `Foo` is a trait.

So if you want to abstract over behavior, you have to write a trait that captures this behavior. The problem with your case: **traits do not allow to specify fields**. In other word: you cannot say "all types implementing this trait need to have the field `name`). However, you can of course just create **a getter method** (in Rust it's usually called like the field, without the `get`):

```rust
trait HasName {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

fn get_meta<T: HasName>(args: T) -> Option<meta::ObjectMeta> {
   Some(meta::ObjectMeta {
       name: Some(args.name().clone()),
   })
}
```

Using a getter method instead of a field should work in basically all situations.

---

As a side note: there are [some early considerations](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/fields-in-traits-rfc/blob/master/0000-fields-in-traits.md) about adding fields to traits. This discussion is in very early stages, though. There is not even an official RFC, so don't expect this feature anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Such a proposition has been made -- to have a virtual field inside a trait -- but nothing has been accepted for now. You can use a getter, though, and do some polymorphism:

```
struct Apple;

struct Orange;

trait Named {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

impl Named for Apple {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        "Golden"
    }
}

impl Named for Orange {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        "Orange"
    }
}

fn get_name<T>(named: T) -> String where T: Named {
    named.name().to_owned()
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(get_name(Apple), "Golden");
    assert_eq!(get_name(Orange), "Orange");
}
```